# Android edittext not updating

Tags: android, android-edittext

My edittext's methods work properly as I have checked it on debbug, but in the graphical layout there are no changes at all.

When changing the text programatically, in the graphical layout doesn't appear, but if I try myedittext.getText() on the debbug expressions/watches it returns the correct string, so the settext() method is working OK but the changes are not shown.

Here is the code:

```
public class easmpartne extends FragmentActivity {

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.easmpartne);

        FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this,
                getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("General"),
                Tab1.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Categ"),
                Tab2.class, null);

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        viewGeneral= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, null);
        viewCateg= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, null);

        txtRef=(EditText)viewGeneral.findViewById(R.id.txtRef);
        txtRef.setText("example");
        txtRef.setEnabled(false);
     }
}
```

Neither settext nor setenabled seems no have any effect on the graphical layout when executing.

easmpartne.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:fillViewport="true"
       android:scrollbars="none">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1" />

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

tab1.xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linlayouteasmpartne"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tablelayout1">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/ref"
                    android:id="@+id/textView" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txtRef" />
            </TableRow>

....
```

(I don't know if this could be a problem with de tabhost as it is the first time I use it)

Is that the correct way to get the edittext in this case?

What are the possible problems/solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean it does not appear while you´ve got a breakpoint and debugging??

Comment: The changes doesn't appear  anyway, on run mode or debbug mode.

Comment: when do you set the tab content to be `viewGeneral`?

Comment: in Tab1.class , in the onCreateView it returns "inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);" .....So in the code i was getting that tab1.xml to make the changes

Comment: mmh... nono... as far as I can see you´re reading the views inside the `onCreate`: `viewGeneral= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, null);`. You see?? you´re working with a different reference. Do the assign (for a test) finding the textview inside the onCreateView. It´ll do the trick

Comment: yes, the way you say works fine, but could it be possible to access to the elements in the tab1.xml layout within the easmpartne.class?. If it's not possible i can manage to make it work with your advice, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

the point is, you see, that the layout is not kind of a shared variable so when you or the runtime reads it, it instances all views referenced inside and you have to stick to it. Then you follow the lifecycle of the components so to set the values you want you should do it in `onViewStateRestored(Bundle)` when the view is actually done or something like that, or onStart or so